# My regex is not replacing correctly

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-replace

I have this regex: `/(?:(?<=(?:style=["])).*)(line-height.*?)[;"]/i`

```
$regex = '/(?:(?<=(?:style=["])).*)(line-height.*?)[;"]/i';

preg_replace("/(?:(?<=(?:style=[\"'])).*)(line-height.*?)[;\"]/i", "HELLO", $input);
```

This is the input:

```
    <li><span style="line-height: 20.14399986267089px">500.00dkk</span></li>
<li style="color:red; line-height: 21.14399986267089px"></li>
```

I want to replace only the occurrences of  "line-height: SOMENUMBERpx" with HELLO (It also has to preceded by the style tag):
but I can not make it work correctly. Right now it replaces the line-height properties, but it also replace,: *color:red*, which I do not want.

This is the output I want:

```
<li><span style=HELLO>500.00dkk</span></li> 
<li style="color:red; HELLO"></li>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are those `line-height` styles always inside `<li>` and `<span>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **\K** here.`\K resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match`

```
style=.*?\Kline-height.*?(?=[;"])
```

Try this.[**See demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/35)

This will make sure that only `line=height...` will be replced and it is preceded by `style=` as well

Comment: Awesome an even better solution:)

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `DOM` parser to extract the style attributes and modify the contents using `preg_replace()`:

```
$input = <<<EOF
<li><span style="line-height: 20.14399986267089px">500.00dkk</span></li>
<li style="color:red; line-height: 21.14399986267089px"></li>
EOF;

# Create a document from input
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($input);

# Create an XPath selector
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

# Modify values of the style attributes
foreach($selector->query('//@style') as $style) {
    $style->nodeValue = preg_replace(
        '/line-height:\s*[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?px\s*;?/',
        'HELLO;',
        $style->nodeValue
    );
}

# Output the modified document
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

The advantage of using `DOM` and `XPath` is that you can reliably access the style attributes in any nested level even if HTML content gets freaky. Also it is easy to maintain if the HTML structure changes in future or if you want to specify a littler closer which style attributes should change.

Take the following query for example, it selects only style attributes of `<span>` tags having a class `even` and being child (in any nested level) of a `div` with `id="foo"`.

```xml
//div[@id="foo"]//span[contains(@class, "even")]/@style
```

You'll have a a lot of fun if you try this with a regex! :)

---

About the `CSS` part. I decided to use a regex for that since the only thing I could imagine of which could break the regex would be something like:

```
<span style="background:url('line-height:2px');">
```

Since `line-height:2px` is a valid UNIX filename, the above could be possible. But hey! :) If you really care about that you would need to use a CSS parser for that job.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regular expression you want

```
(line-height:\s+\d+\.\d+px)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-bCA9DgMdVSIteLQ)

Comment: but I also want to make sure that is preceded by the style tag, like I have done i my regex.

Comment: Can you please write the expected output? should it be  <li><span style=HELLO>500.00dkk</span></li>
<li style="color:red; HELLO"></li>  ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I could use the references for each group to insert that group back into the replacement, so I did not loose the *color:red* part.

```
preg_replace ('/(?<=style=["])(.*)(line-height.*?)[;"]/', '$1HELLO', $input);
```

This gave me the desired result.